# while loop in python diamond pattern

Tags: python

Please code with only while loop to print the diamond pattern in python. This is the code I tried but it prints only the half diamond correctly.

```
n = int(input())
h=1
k=1
while h <=(n+1)/2:
    b=1
    while b<=(n+1)/2-h:
        print(' ',end='')
        b=b+1
    j=1
    while j<=k:
        print('*',end='')
        j=j+1
    k=k+2
    print()
    h=h+1

n=(n-((n+1)/2))
h=1
while n>=0:
    b=1
    while b<= h:
        print(" ",end='')
        b=b+1
    j=1
    while j<=(n*2)- h:
        print("*",end='')
        j=j+1
    print()
    n=n-1
    h=h+1`
```

Please correct and add .I am not able to print the whole diamond. Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use `while` loops instead of `for _ in range(...)` loops?

Comment: You need to convert the input to an integer. It shouldn't run at all.

Comment: The loop for the bottom half should be similar to the loop for the top half, except it goes in reverse. You don't have anything analogous to the `k` variable, which should be reduced by 2 each time.

Comment: n=(n-((n+1)/2))
i=1
k=1

while n>=0:
    b=1
    while b<=i:
        print(" ",end='')
        b=b+1
    j=1
    while j<=k:
        print("*",end='')
        j=j+1
    print()
    k=k-2
    n=n-1
    i=i+1
    

should it be something like this